# Not able to access public folder in express server from a react app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, content-security-policy, transpiler

### The Problem

I get a broken image in the browser when rendering the path to images saved on backend (using express).
I know there are similar questions, but non could solve the issue for me.

### Details

I have this on my `server.ts` file running in `http://localhost:5000`:

```
import express from 'express';
export const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

import path from 'path';
const pathToFile = path.resolve(__dirname, './public');

import cors from 'cors';
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(pathToFile));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I have this on one of my react app components running in `http://localhost:3000`:

```
{petToRender.petPicture &&
<img
src={`http://localhost:5000/${petToRender.petPicture.replace(/\\/g, "/").replace('public/','')}`}
/>}
```

I tried it also without `.replace('public/','')`, but it doesn't work either.

### More refernces and checks

The data on mongoDB for `petToRender.petPicture` looks like the screenshot shows and is fetched correctly:

[image]

The image is uploaded to `./public/images` properly using multer:

[image]

On the browser's console - I get:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/images/61b3441440535e9b69a74356.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

When I enter the images direct link the console also show the following:

```
Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback
```

Comment: Since you use Typescript i assume you have to transpile it to javascript first and it's likely placed in another folder like ./build, right? If so is the path you pass to express.static correct? Try to log the `__dirname` variable to make sure it points to the correct folder. Or try `console.log(pathToFile)`

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it places the js version in a ./dist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Molda 's comment -

I changed to `const pathToFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public');` (added one more '.') and the images are loaded properly!